# Do not match if within tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I have this regex which detects url formatted text:

```
/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/
```

so it would detect something like `http://google.com`

My problem is that I do not want it to detect the links when the links are inside tags such as `<a href="http://google.com">http://www.google.com</a>` - so in there it should **not** detect anything. Help?

EDIT - I do NOT want to match the anchor tag. The above regex matches links inside anchor tags which is what I do **not** want. I need it to match links only outside of tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

this one should work

```
/(?!href.*?=.*?['"]+)(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/
```

Comment: This regex is matching the opposite of what I want. This is matching the anchor tag and the link

Comment: @user969622: no, ?! ensures it's not there

Comment: @user969622, maybe you are matching against the opposite of what you want therefore you are getting the opposite match of what you want for the opposite target. bam, double negative!

Comment: @TylerCrompton: - minus - = plus

Comment: Your expression matches exactly the same set of strings as the OPs expression, since your lookahead can never match when the rest of the expression does.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?<!href=['"])(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/
```

Comment: Hmm after some usage it stopped functioning in some cases such as `<a href="http://www.test.com/"></a> http://www.test.com/` If two alike links are present it matches both of them. How can this be fixed?